# how to get dar with multi-threading enabled

Tags: backup, multi-core, dar

I'm using a on a System76 Silverback desktop machine dual Xeon with 16 cores (32 hyperthreads) with large hard drives, and thinking to use dar(1) for my backups.  I see that the man page mentions its capability to use multithreading during compression.  I'd love that, but it appears to have been disabled at compile-time.

Currently running Xubuntu Focal Fossa, blocked somehow from going up to Jammy, but I just posted a question about that.  It was originally Ubuntu, but I switched to Xubuntu as soon as I got it.

Anyway, how do I get this capability?

Comment: It looks like that depends on the availability of `libthreadar` - [dar in mantic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/mantic/dar) depends on [libthreadar1000](https://packages.ubuntu.com/mantic/libthreadar1000) and appear to be the first release that packages it